# How to save a full html page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to save a webpage from my rails 4 application to disk, using

> send_data(render_to_string, :filename => "foo.html").

The file is saved alright, but the css is missing.

I tried adding the type attribute, like so:

> send_data(render_to_string, :filename => "foo.html", **:type => "text/html"**)

but it didn't help.

How can I save the file with all the css (and other assets potentially), so that if I click on the saved file I'll see the same thing that I attempted to save?

Comment: The title does not match the question. Do you want to save the html page, or all the related files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`render_to_string` renders only the HTML part. It returns exact the same string as the browser receives when he loads the HTML page. Stylesheets and other assets will be loaded in additional requests. Therefore, I only see one option: `render_to_string` an HTML template/layout with inline CSS.

Another option might be to open the *save as* dialog with JavaScript. But there seems no standardized way to do so.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds right. I am surprised though that there is no standard way to do it. What I did in the end was exactly what you suggested. I stuffed the relevant CSS into a partial between two <style> tags and called that partial only when the user clicks the download link:
`= render 'enable_download_css' if @download`