# Generate a static html from view using rake (in Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a an extremely slow-loaded sitemap style of view that iterates through category-trees, with subcategories (of other objects) with conditionals etc. It is a mess but I believe it is needed for the website. I have tried my best to create smart queries but I am still at 400+ queries and super long load times.

The page itself is not subject to be changed very often and could easily be transformed to a static html-page. I am using Memcachier with a 200 days expiry. The problem is that Memcachier is always full (and I don't want to pay the extra money for more space) so my feeling is that it pushes out this cached page more often than those 200 days (I see it in my Scout reports much more often than that).

What I would like to do is to schedule a rake that would "visit" the page and create a static html-page of it once in a while. Is that possible? How could that be done, in that case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880051/how-to-save-a-full-html-page-in-rails this might also help, you can just visit the route like a normal url and it saves it to disk

Comment: Yes! This is the answer! Thank you so much. Put this as the answer and get thy reward :)

Answer (score 2):

Rendering ERB templates is quite easy in Ruby/Rails, here is one example of doing that.

Given this template

```
# You can place this really anywhere in your project
# lib/tasks/static.html.erb

<h1><%= Time.current %></h1>
<p><%= name %></p>
```

Then you can use that in your Rake task like this.
What this does is read the ERB template file and then renders it using the data you provide it. Finally it writes the generated HTML file to the public folder of your app.

```rb
# lib/tasks/static_generate.rake

namespace :static_generate do
  task run: :environment do
    html_result = template.result_with_hash(generated_data)

    File.open(Rails.root.join('public/static.html'), 'w') do |new_file|
      new_file.puts(html_result)
    end
  end

  def template
    path = Rails.root.join('lib/tasks/static.html.erb')
    file = File.open(path).read
    ERB.new(file)
  end

  def generated_data
    # Do your complicated logic here
    # or delegate it to a class somewhere else
    { name: 'test123' }
  end
end
```

You then call your rake test from the terminal with

```
rails static_generate:run
```